# Можно ли в массиве ставить тексты?

Tags: javascript

есть например такой текст и их около 100, можно ли ставить их в массиве или по другому нужно сделать?

При нажатии на  кнопку New Info появляется информация о рандомной стране, например про Россию, при повторном нажатии появляется другая рандомная информация про другую страну и т.д. , для этого и нужен такой массив, вопрос мой в том, что будет ли правильно использовать массивы так или есть другой вариант для этой идеи

```
let x = [Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries]
```

и так далее...

Comment: Добавьте больше сведений в вопрос

Comment: можно............

Comment: @MaximLensky не понял ваши точки

Comment: Что означает "можно"? Это не запрещено, значит, можно. А вот целесообразно ли - уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @Эникейщик я об этом и спрашиваю будет ли правильно так писать? или есть другой вариант для такого текста?

Comment: Т.к. непонятно для чего это нужно, то и ответить на вопрос нельзя.

Comment: @Эникейщик переформировал вопрос

Comment: Почему не объекты? Погибче будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, вот пример:

```
let text_arr = ["Happy", "new", "year!"];
```

С наступающим Вас!